# Multiple if condition optimization

Tags: algorithms, performance, conditions

Often I find conditional statements such as:

```
if (life_max < max):
  if (expand):
     do life_max = max
else:
  if (life_max > max) and not (expand):
     do life_max = max;
```

Although readable, it feels a bit clunky and I'm curious as to the best way to simplify it while still keeping it readable.

Comment: "Although readable..." If it's readable, and it works, and there are no performance problems, it's just fine. Can't ask for more.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some code is inherently complicated. We can shuffle the code around to emphasize one aspect or another, but we can't really simplify it.

Your code looks like an example of code that cannot be inherently simplified or optimized.

At most, it could be cleaned up *syntactically*. E.g. in Python:

```py
if life_max < max_value and expand:
  life_max = max_value
elif life_max > max_value and not expand:
  life_max = max_value
```

The above phrasing emphasizes that we're selecting branches primarily based on the result of the `life_max <=> max` comparison. We could alternatively emphasize that we're clipping the upper/lower bound depending on the `expand` boolean:

```py
if expand:
  life_max = max(life_max, max_value)
else:
  life_max = min(life_max, max_value)
```

Which phrasing is most appropriate depends on the context of this code. Code does not just communicate instructions to the computer, it also communicates intent to other programmers who will read this code in the future (such as yourself in a couple of months). Where the intent is not obvious from the code, adding a comment would be a very good idea.

Comment: I can make it shorter (in C and C-like languages): if ((expand ? life_max < max_value : life_max > max_value)) life_max = max_value. Not more readable obviously, so leave it as it is.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sure, but “shorter” isn't necessarily “faster”, “simpler”, or “clearer”. I love code golfing as a sport but wouldn't tolerate it in production code (and I say this as someone who likes Perl).

Comment: Spelling it out as you did, did the trick for me. I just have issues reading code like in my OP and it always leaves me puzzled because I'm trying to optimize or figure out a shortcut.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata focus that energy on readability. Measure readability by getting others to read your code.

Comment: @ChibuezeOpata - don't think of it in terms of optimizing or finding some clever way to shorten it, rather, think in terms of how can you rewrite the code so that the reader can immediately tell what it's trying to accomplish. In your original code, and even in amon's first example, you have to mentally parse what the conditions are, what they mean, and infer why the developer wrote the code snippet in the first place, while in amon's second example you can pretty much read the intent right away: "Oh, if expand is set, then expand if necessary, otherwise shrink if necessary".